# Erro 429 on Scraping data from Expedia

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, http-error

I wrote a script with axios to scrape data from Expedia GraphQL API.

It worked for 1 year, and now I'm getting error 429 too many requests on the first request that I try to do.

Curious fact: When I put the query on postman, I get the response correctly. I tried to copy the exactly same request that works on Postman to NodeJS with a lot of libs(axios, request, http) and I always get error 429 - Too Many Requests.

- I tried a lot of different header settings and still not working.

I'm posting the query part of code below to be more easy to understand whats happening.

```
    axiosExpedia
            .post('https://www.expedia.com.br/graphql', 
            { variables: 
                { context: 
                     { siteId: 69,
                         locale: 'pt_BR',
                         eapid: 0,
                         currency: 'BRL',
                         device: { type: 'DESKTOP' },
                         identity: 
                            { duaid: 'c4e8e73c-16fa-4672-af53-62380e414523',
                                expUserId: '-1',
                                tuid: '-1',
                                authState: 'ANONYMOUS' },
                         debugContext: { abacusOverrides: [], alterMode: 'RELEASED' } },
                    propertyId: '16024731',
                    sortBy: 'NEWEST_TO_OLDEST',
                    filters: 
                     { includeRecentReviews: true,
                         includeRatingsOnlyReviews: true,
                         travelerType: [] },
                    pagination: { size: 10, startingIndex: 10 },
                    searchCriteria: 
                     { primary: 
                            { dateRange: 
                                 { checkInDate: { day: 20, month: 11, year: 2020 },
                                     checkOutDate: { day: 22, month: 11, year: 2020 } },
                                destination: 
                                 { regionName: 'Brasil',
                                     regionId: '23',
                                     coordinates: null,
                                     pinnedPropertyId: null,
                                     propertyIds: null },
                                rooms: [ { adults: 2, children: [] } ] },
                         secondary: 
                            { counts: [],
                                ranges: [],
                                selections: 
                                 [ { id: 'sort', value: 'RECOMMENDED' },
                                     { id: 'regionId', value: '23' },
                                     { id: 'privacyTrackingState', value: 'CAN_TRACK' },
                                     { id: 'useRewards', value: 'SHOP_WITHOUT_POINTS' } ] } } },
             query: 'query PropertyFilteredReviewsQuery($context: ContextInput!, $propertyId: String!, $sortBy: PropertyReviewSort!, $filters: PropertyReviewFiltersInput!, $pagination: PaginationInput!, $searchCriteria: PropertySearchCriteriaInput) {\n  propertyReviewSummaries(context: $context, propertyIds: [$propertyId]) {\n    ...__PropertyReviewSummaryFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  propertyInfo(context: $context, propertyId: $propertyId) {\n    reviewInfo(sortBy: $sortBy, pagination: $pagination, filters: $filters, searchCriteria: $searchCriteria) {\n      ...__PropertyReviewsListFragment\n      ...__WriteReviewLinkFragment\n      sortAndFilter {\n        ...TravelerTypeFragment\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __PropertyReviewSummary__: __type(name: "PropertyReviewSummary") {\n    possibleTypes {\n      name\n    }\n  }\n  __PropertyReviews__: __type(name: "PropertyReviews") {\n    possibleTypes {\n      name\n    }\n  }\n  __PropertyReview__: __type(name: "PropertyReview") {\n    possibleTypes {\n      name\n    }\n  }\n  __ReviewThemes__: __type(name: "ReviewThemes") {\n    possibleTypes {\n      name\n    }\n  }\n  __ManagementResponse__: __type(name: "ManagementResponse") {\n    possibleTypes {\n      name\n    }\n  }\n  __SortAndFilterViewModel__: __type(name: "SortAndFilterViewModel") {\n    possibleTypes {\n      name\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment __PropertyReviewSummaryFragment on PropertyReviewSummary {\n  overallScoreWithDescription\n  propertyReviewCountDetails {\n    fullDescription\n    __typename\n  }\n  reviewDisclaimer\n  reviewSummaryDetails {\n    label\n    ratingPercentage\n    formattedRatingOutOfMax\n    __typename\n  }\n  totalCount {\n    raw\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment __PropertyReviewsListFragment on PropertyReviews {\n  summary {\n    paginateAction {\n      text\n      analytics {\n        referrerId\n        linkName\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  reviews {\n    ...ReviewParentFragment\n    managementResponses {\n      ...ReviewChildFragment\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ReviewParentFragment on PropertyReview {\n  id\n  superlative\n  locale\n  title\n  reviewScoreWithDescription {\n    label\n    value\n    __typename\n  }\n  text\n  stayDuration\n  submissionTime {\n    formatted(format: "d MMM yyyy")\n    __typename\n  }\n  themes {\n    ...ReviewThemeFragment\n    __typename\n  }\n  ...FeedbackIndicatorFragment\n  ...AuthorFragment\n  ...PhotosFragment\n  ...TravelersFragment\n  ...ReviewTranslationInfoFragment\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment AuthorFragment on PropertyReview {\n  reviewAuthorAttribution {\n    text\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment PhotosFragment on PropertyReview {\n  id\n  photos {\n    description\n    url\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment TravelersFragment on PropertyReview {\n  travelers\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ReviewThemeFragment on ReviewThemes {\n  icon {\n    id\n    description\n    __typename\n  }\n  label\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment FeedbackIndicatorFragment on PropertyReview {\n  helpfulReviewVotes\n  feedbackIndicator {\n    label\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ReviewTranslationInfoFragment on PropertyReview {\n  translationInfo {\n    loadingTranslationText\n    targetLocale\n    translatedBy {\n      description\n      __typename\n    }\n    translationCallToActionLabel\n    seeOriginalText\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment ReviewChildFragment on ManagementResponse {\n  id\n  header {\n    text\n    __typename\n  }\n  response\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment TravelerTypeFragment on SortAndFilterViewModel {\n  sortAndFilter {\n    name\n    label\n    options {\n      label\n      isSelected\n      optionValue\n      description\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment __WriteReviewLinkFragment on PropertyReviews {\n  writeReviewLink {\n    link {\n      uri {\n        value\n        relativePath\n        __typename\n      }\n      clientSideAnalytics {\n        referrerId\n        linkName\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    value\n    accessibilityLabel\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n' })
```

[image: Screenshot Postman]

Comment: An screenshot of the succesful Postman request would be useful.

Comment: I insert a screenshot on post.

Comment: did you check their API docs? they may have whitelisted postman requests or restricted their API access placing a limit for certain IPs, or restrict access for browser clients and not for server clients and so on. Possibly, they do not even allow scraping, since in some countries is forbidden. What you are asking here is very broad

Comment: do you get a `retry after` header as well as the 429?

Comment: I tried set Postman's header in NodeJS and I got 429.

Comment: @rags2riches I don't receive `retry after`

Comment: @RobsonJeanPenteado because it is an optional header so most certainly have restrictred their API usage. Again, best to check their docs because there are so many variables here e.g. your country of residence, how you make API request, if it is legal to scrape their data and so on.

Comment: same issue here. @RobsonJeanPenteado did you find any fix?